# Hadoop copy a directory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there an HDFS API that can copy an entire local directory to the HDFS? I found an API for copying files but is there one for directories?

Answer (score 18):

Use the [Hadoop FS shell](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.19.2/hdfs_shell.html). Specifically:

```
$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/to/local hdfs:///path/to/hdfs
```

If you want to do it programmatically, create two FileSystems (one Local and one HDFS) and use [the FileUtil class](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html)

Comment: i need to do this programatically. not from the shell

Comment: Can hadoop fs support copy from a file share? I never succeed to do that

Answer (score 11):

I tried copying from the directory using

```
/hadoop/core/bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/grad04/lopez/TPCDSkew/ /export/hadoop1/lopez/Join/TPCDSkew
```

It gave me an error saying Target is a directory . I then modified it to

```
/hadoop/core/bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/grad04/lopez/TPCDSkew/*.* /export/hadoop1/lopez/Join/TPCDSkew
```

it works .

Comment: This is with reference to hadoop version 0.20.

Comment: this problem has now been fixed and this notation is no longer needed. However the OP did not specify a hadoop version so this answer may still apply to old versions.

Answer (score 2):

In Hadoop version:

```
Hadoop 2.4.0.2.1.1.0-390
```

(And probably later; I have only tested this specific version as it is the one I have)

You can copy entire directories recursively without any special notation using `copyFromLocal` e.g.,:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/on/disk /path/on/hdfs
```

which works even when `/path/on/disk` is a directory containing subdirectories and files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `put` command:

```
$ hadoop fs -put /local/path hdfs:/path
```

Answer (score -2):

For programmer, you also can use copyFromLocalFile. Here is an example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val hdfsConfig = new Configuration
val hdfsURI = "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hdfsData"
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsURI), hdfsConfig)

val oriPath = new Path("#your_localpath/customer.csv")
val targetFile = new Path("hdfs://your_hdfspath/customer.csv")
hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(oriPath, targetFile)
```

Comment: This is for a single file, OP asked for a directory